# Tire mesh rotates faster than wheelcollider in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, racing

I have a car in Unity. Scripts are C#. I have noticed that my tire meshes' rotation is faster than whellcollider rotation. I am using this code for wheel rotation

```
 flWheel.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(flWheel.localEulerAngles.x, flWheelCollider.steerAngle - flWheel.localEulerAngles.z, flWheel.localEulerAngles.z);
 frWheel.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(frWheel.localEulerAngles.x, frWheelCollider.steerAngle - frWheel.localEulerAngles.z, frWheel.localEulerAngles.z);

 flWheel.Rotate(flWheelCollider.rpm / 60 * 360 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
 frWheel.Rotate(frWheelCollider.rpm / 60 * 360 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
 rlWheel.Rotate(rlWheelCollider.rpm / 60 * 360 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
 rrWheel.Rotate(rrWheelCollider.rpm / 60 * 360 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
```

I found this from [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/853476/making-mesh-rotate-with-wheelcollider.html)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Edit:

Using AquaGeneral's answer I could able to solve rotation problem. But now front right tire position changed to rear left tire position and  rear right tire rotated 180 on Y axis. need help

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The code you found is not the ideal way to go about this. Instead of figuring out exactly what is causing the issue for you, just use the builtin function: [WheelCollider.GetWorldPose](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WheelCollider.GetWorldPose.html).

From the [official Unity Wheel Collider Tutorial](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/WheelColliderTutorial.html) in the `ApplyLocalPositionToVisuals` function/method:

```
// Get the child of the wheel that has the mesh renderer
Transform visualWheel = collider.transform.GetChild(0); 

Vector3 position;
Quaternion rotation;
collider.GetWorldPose(out position, out rotation);

visualWheel.transform.position = position;
visualWheel.transform.rotation = rotation;
```

Comment: Rotation problem solved. But tire meshes positions changed. How fix it?

Comment: @SajithaRathnayake Could you explain further about what you mean by "tire meshes positions changed"?